# Append error message to target ".not.empty"?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have several tests that check if a string is empty.

```js
expect(Cypress.env('ACT_PROVIDER_KEYS')).to.be.an('string').not.empty;
```

Is there a way to add a message to `.not.empty` to specifically indicate which test failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom error message can be given as the second argument to `expect`.

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('73450550', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const ACT_PROVIDER_KEYS = '';
    expect(ACT_PROVIDER_KEYS, 'api provider keys is empty').to.be.an('string').not.empty;
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  73450550
    1) should pass


  0 passing (7ms)
  1 failing

  1) 73450550
       should pass:
     AssertionError: api provider keys is empty: expected '' not to be empty
      at Context.<anonymous> (src/stackoverflow/73450550/index.test.js:6:83)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
```